# Extracting facebook user information from a particular page using facebook4j in java

Tags: java, eclipse, facebook

I want to extract user information(*age,location etc)* from a particular page. 
*For example*: My search string is *"obama"*. So I want the information of all users who have liked or commented in this particular page of *obama*.

I am able to achieve this to some extent by:

```
public static String getFacebookPostes(Facebook facebook, String searchPost)
            throws FacebookException {
        String searchResult = "Item : " + searchPost + "\n";
        StringBuilder searchMessage = new StringBuilder();
        ResponseList<Post> results = facebook.getPosts(searchPost);

        //facebook.getFriends(new Reading().fields("gender"));
        /*System.out.println("success");
        System.out.println(facebook.getMe().getFirstName());*/      

        String userId="";
        for (Post post : results) {
            System.out.println(post.getMessage());
            searchMessage.append(post.getMessage() + "\n");
            for (int j = 0; j < post.getComments().size(); j++) {
             searchMessage.append(post.getComments().get(j).getFrom()
                        .getName()
                        + ", ");
             searchMessage.append(post.getComments().get(j).getMessage()
                        + ", ");
             searchMessage.append(post.getComments().get(j).getCreatedTime()
                        + ", ");
             searchMessage.append(post.getComments().get(j).getLikeCount()
                        + "\n");

                         userId=post.getComments().get(j).getFrom().getId();
             User user = facebook.getUser(userId);
             System.out.println(user);
            }
        }

        searchResult = searchResult + searchMessage.toString();
        System.out.println(searchMessage.toString());
        return searchResult;
    }
```

Reference URL: http://www.devx.com/Java/how-to-integrate-facebook-and-twitter-with-java-applications.html

But this gives me only *Name, Username, Gender, Locale, Profile link..* It gives me null values for location,birthday,email..

Through googling, some people suggested that "It all depends on what information the user has made public". So i created a test account and made all the information public and commented on the obama page. It displays the information i made public, except for the email and birthday.. How can i extract these 2 parameters?

Any help,suggestion,guidance is appreciated.

**PS**:I am using eclipse kepler and *facebook4j-core-2.0.2*

Comment: I am able to extract the location parameter now. But still getting null values for birthday and email.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have set the right OAuthPermissions like email,user_birthday,read_stream etc..

***`configurationBuilder.setOAuthPermissions("email, publish_stream, id, name, first_name, last_name, read_stream , generic");`***

Comment: Have already set the OAuthPermissions... Both in the code as well as in the FB App.Still no luck!!

Answer (score 0):

Try this....

Use FacebookClient object....Get **access token** from **Facebook developer tools** and in the fetchobject() pass username.....you can extract **username** from url's using some sort of regular expressions or other methods....

**N.B** :- Result depends on the fact that which all fields are made public...

```
public static FacebookClient facebookClient;
public static void main(String[] args) throws FacebookException 
{

        facebookClient = new DefaultFacebookClient("ur access token");
        String result= facebookClient.fetchObject("username", String.class);
        System.out.println(result);

    }
}
```